# Why does Clang not warn when assigning a non-matching block to "void(^)()" (in contrast to "void(^)(void)")?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang, objective-c-blocks

Suppose you have three methods on an object:

```
- (void) handleBlockA:(void(^)())block;
- (void) handleBlockB:(void(^)(void))block;
- (void) handleBlockC:(dispatch_block_t)block;
```

Now you call them:

```
[self handleBlockA:^(NSString*s){}];
[self handleBlockB:^(NSString*s){}];
[self handleBlockC:^(NSString*s){}];
```

In a clean Xcode project, Clang will **not** warn you about the `handleBlockA:` call, but will throw errors for the other two. In fact the first one will happily run and crash once `block()` is called inside the `handleBlockA:` method (in `objc_storeStrong`).

Why? What is the difference between `void(^)()` and `void(^)(void)`?
Is there a compiler flag that will make Clang also warn about the `handleBlockA:` call?

Comment: Agree about the question being a duplicate. The only difference seems to be that in my case the app crashed. And hopefully mentioning the crash location saves some future person googling around a bit of work.